# Regex help: Parse a series of URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse a series of URLs that can come in the following potential structures:

```
protocol://category
protocol://category/:id
protocol://category/:id#hash
```

for example:

```
protocol://feed > feed
protocol://blog/123 > feed, 123
protocol://video/123#ABC > feed, 123, ABC
```

The `protocol://` is always static, and the other items are dynamic. I need to be able to pull these items into an array of:

```
[1] category
[2] id (if present)
[3] hash (if present)
```

I've cobbled together a seemingly overcomplicated regex of `(?:protocol:\/\/)(\w+)(?:\/?(\w*)(?:(?:$|#)?(.+$))?)?` which seems to work, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

I've tried testing in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/orXybB/1)

Comment: `/protocol:\/\/(\w+)(?:\/:([\w-]+)(?:#(.+))?)?$/gm` might be bit more efficient

Comment: `protocol:\/\/(\w+)(?:\/:(\w+)(?:[$#](.+$))?)?`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aRU61N/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should match exactly what you want in a simple way

```
protocol:\/\/(\w+)(?:\/:?(\w+))?(?:#([\S]+))?
```

[image]
[see example here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/orXybB/3)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, in JS you could do this:

```
s.slice(11).split(/\/+|#/g);
```

The slice just cuts off the protocol portion since it seems to be irrelevant to what you need. Of course, this method assumes that the url is properly formatted according to the three options you provided, otherwise you could get the following:

```
protocol://video/ABC   --->   ["video", "ABC"]
protocol://video/#ABC  --->   ["video", "", "ABC"]
protocol://video/123#  --->   ["video", "123", ""]
protocol:///video/123  --->   ["", "video", "123"]
```